# Why is this PHP exception not caught?

Tags: php, exception

I have this very simple **PHP 8** code in which there is (voluntary) an error. Just to see if the exception is caught.

```
try {
        $school = $this->schoolRepository->insert($request->all());
        $fake = 1 / 0;
        return new SchoolResource($school);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json('bad request' . $ex->getMessage(), 400);
    }
```

And surprise ! The exception is not caught. I receive the error of the division :

```
 {
"message": "Division by zero",
"exception": "DivisionByZeroError",
"file": "D:\\Workspace\\school-back-v2\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\SchoolController.php",
"line": 48,
"trace": [
```

Why is this exception not caught ?

Comment: That doesn't look like the output of an uncaught exception though. Where do you see that? Looks like a part of some JSON? Can you post the complete error/output?

Comment: Is this php 7? php 7 does not throw for `/`, php 8 does (I've long stopped trying to reason the the design decisions of php, so I don't know WHY)

Comment: I think the exception was caught and the catch-handler makes this JSON output.

Comment: It's not an exception, it's an error. You need to do: `catch (\Error $e)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DivisionByZeroError` inherits from `Error`, so you'd better catch the base interface `Throwable`.

```
catch (\Throwable $e)
```

Comment: Thanks shingo. It works, and I have understood.

Answer (score 0):

change the  return response()->json('bad request' . $ex->getMessage(), 400); to  return response()->json('bad request' . $e->getMessage(), 400);